# sharekit/sharekit not displaying link when sharing on facebook and twitter

Tags: iphone, ios, sharekit

I'm using sharekit/sharekit API to share via mail,twitter,facebook

```
NSDictionary *table = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SHKTwitter", SHKLocalizedString(@"Twitter", nil), @"SHKFacebook", SHKLocalizedString(@"Facebook", nil), @"SHKMail", SHKLocalizedString(@"Email", nil),@"SHKTextMessage", SHKLocalizedString(@"Text", nil),nil];

Class SharersClass = NSClassFromString([table objectForKey:"Facebook"]);
NSString *shareMsg = @"share message";
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:shareMsg];
item.url = shareUrl;
[SharersClass performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
```

the sharing works but my problem is that the url is not displayed to the user in the facebook pop up however it's displayed on the user wall on facebook.com ... 
the same case happens with twitter ... but the links appears in mail and text sharing ... 
any idea what might be the problem ?

Comment: can you please elaborate the question ? what I understand is you are not able to see the link in mobile device but you can see it in website .. right ?\

Comment: exactly this is the problem ! that happens with facebook and twitter only

Comment: try something out .. may be some problem in the configuration .. genrally this thing shouldnt happen .

Comment: I'm gonna try and download the sharekit again the replace it with the one i have !

Comment: hmm .. sounds nice ... do it and tell me what happend then !